# Map array of key variants to key to search dictionary in Swift or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, key-value

When users enter a search term, I would like to use the search term as a key to search a dictionary using valueForKey. If the key is always the same, it works great.

```
NSString *key = @"bread";  //from user Input such as self.textField.text
NSDictionary *blurbs = @{ @"bread" : @"We offer a variety of artisan breads baked fresh daily",@"produce" : @"We offer the finest produce sourced locally from nearby farms"};
NSString *value =  [blurbs valueForKey:key];
```

However, frequently there are variants of the key that the user might enter. I am looking for a way to map from these variants to a single key so that I can use  valueForKey. Ideally, I'd like to do this for the entire dictionary in one fell swoop.

non-working code:

```
NSString *key = @"rye";  //from user Input such as self.textField.text
NSDictionary *blurbs =@{ @"rye,whole wheat,bread,breads,rolls,whole grain" : @"We offer a variety of artisan breads baked fresh daily",@"produce,vegetables,tomatos,lettuce,kale,salad" : @"We offer the finest produce sourced locally from nearby farms"};
NSString *descript =  [blurbs valueForKey:key];
```

Naturally, I could list all the arrays separately and  match the input string to arrays to find the appropriate key but this would be very complicated and create problems for maintenance. It would be better to have everything together.

Is there any efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What kind of key is this: `@"rye,whole wheat,bread,breads,rolls,whole grain"`. That's really unusuall... I think you might rethink your structure. Also, does "ry" instead of "rye" should match for that key?

Comment: It could be this: `NSArray *keysMatched = [[blurbs keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString * _Nonnull key, NSString * _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [[key componentsSeparatedByString:@","] containsObject:keyToMatch];
    }] allObjects];  NSString *descript = [blurbs objectForKey:[keysMatched firstObject]];` but what if there is multiple matches?

Comment: That comma delimited string is really an array of possible values. But I don't think you can have an array as a key. So the idea is to match the searchstring to a term in the array (or comma delimited string) and use the match (as opposed to the full comma delimited string or array) as the key to find the value in the dict.  Which I think is what your code snippet is designed to do.  I will try it out.

Comment: ry should not match. It should be an exact match e.g. rye for rye

Comment: Your code seems to work. What would this be in Swift. Would like to make a swift extension with a function such as valueForKeyFoundInCommaDelimitedString

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to get an Array for a Key, it's possible (not JSON Valid, but possible). Also, why do you really need a "csv" key or an array one? Why can't you set all theses values as a key? `["rye": value1, "whole": value1, "wheat": value1, etc.]`?

Comment: A quick solution might be `let result = csvBlurbs.first(where: { $0.key.components(separatedBy: ",").contains(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(keyToMatch) == .orderedSame } )
})?.value`, but I strongly suggest you to change your modele.

Comment: We have done a bit of that but it doesn't seem like a good idea to repeat all the values in code because when they change, we would need to change them all and errors could creep in. As we see what users are typing (including typos and they type all kinds of things), it seems logical to add these possibilities to the set of possible keys.  But the values should be consistent.  There are actually thousands of key value pairs, so creating a new pair for each variant of the key seems unwieldy. Would love to find a better way--but this approach seems workable.

Comment: If you have a CoreData for instance (or any other Database), what about using many-to-mny relationships?

Comment: WIll look into that. Sorry, I am not so great on Swift. Does the above swift replace the entire objective-c or part of it?